# OpenAm 12 and "DefaultSummary.createDefaultConfig()"

Tags: openam

During OpenAM 12 default installation an exception occurs:

> amConfigurator:12/07/2015 09:15:30:025 AM CET:
>   Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-10,5,main] ERROR:
>   DefaultSummary.createDefaultConfig() java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   com.sun.identity.setup.ServicesDefaultValues.validatePassword(ServicesDefaultValues.java:368)
>     at
>   com.sun.identity.setup.ServicesDefaultValues.setServiceConfigValues(ServicesDefaultValues.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupServlet.processRequest(AMSetupServlet.java:658)
>     at
>   com.sun.identity.config.DefaultSummary.createDefaultConfig(DefaultSummary.java:131)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

while waitting on 
"Please wait... configuration in progress..." screen. I have modified

> /etc/hostname

with

> 127.0.0.1 openam.domain.com

I am entering to the open am installation through
[http://openam.domain.com:8080/openam](http://openam.orange.pl:8080/openam)
link. I have removed previous OpenAm 13 configuration as described here: https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/12.0.0/install-guide/chap-uninstall. 
This is simmiliar error to
https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-5848

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, but in my case I get rid of this error by opening server window in incognito mode. Support pages on their forum hinted of wrong cookie, so either incognito mode or clearing cookies should help.

Answer (score 0):

Uglly solution for testing purpose was to set not null value via IDE debugger in

```
String adminPassword = (String)getContext().getSessionAttribute(
            SessionAttributeNames.CONFIG_VAR_ADMIN_PWD);
```

and

```
String agentPassword = (String)getContext().getSessionAttribute(
            SessionAttributeNames.CONFIG_VAR_AMLDAPUSERPASSWD);
```

inside com.sun.identity.config.DefaultSummary.createDefaultConfig()